# Options to configure the yum log

Tags: logging, centos, yum

Do you know if there are any options to write all informations of console for the yum command into the yum.los file?

For instance by default in yum.log only it writes intalled, ereased or updated nothing about progress or errors

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this any further?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `yum history` and then select the event ID you want and use `yum history info <number>`

View the history list;

```
[root@vm0]# yum history
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   238 | root <root>              | 2018-06-20 08:28 | Update         |    8   
   237 | root <root>              | 2018-06-17 21:44 | E, I, U        |    5 EE
```

Detailed info;

```
[root@vm0]# yum history info 237
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Transaction ID : 237
Begin time     : Sun Jun 17 21:44:06 2018
Begin rpmdb    : 509:98441772be4b269ecf6aac591192709f124cf359
End time       :            21:45:37 2018 (91 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 509:d76a7996c2e749e10675b824fba225121b5e5333
User           : root <root>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : update
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64                       @anaconda-CentOS-201605220104.x86_64/6.8
    Installed     yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch               @base
    Installed     yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64       @anaconda-CentOS-201605220104.x86_64/6.8
    Installed     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch @base
Packages Altered:
    Erase   kernel-ml-4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64         @elrepo-kernel
    Install kernel-ml-4.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64         @elrepo-kernel
    Erase   kernel-ml-devel-4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64   @elrepo-kernel
    Install kernel-ml-devel-4.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64   @elrepo-kernel
    Updated kernel-ml-headers-4.17.1-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 @elrepo-kernel
    Update                    4.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 @elrepo-kernel
Scriptlet output:
   1 warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64/modules.networking failed: No such file or directory
   2 warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64/modules.modesetting failed: No such file or directory
   3 warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64/modules.drm failed: No such file or directory
   4 warning:    erase unlink of /lib/modules/4.17.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64/modules.block failed: No such file or directory
history info
```